# Why does the useEffect hook execute when there's a change in Redux state, even if that specific state is not included in the hook's dependency array?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-hooks

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { useRef, useEffect, useState, useCallback, useMemo} from 'react';

const regionsSelector = state => state.regions;
const cellTypeSelector = state => state.cellType;
const subTypeSelector = state => state.subType;
const genesSelector = state => state.genes ? [state.genes] : [];
const backgroundColorSelector = state => state.backgroundColor;
const depthWriteSelector = state => state.depthWrite;
const radiusScaleSelector = state => state.cellRadiusScale;
const geneExpressionLevelScaleSelector = state => state.geneExpressionLevelScale;


const selectedOptionsSelector = createSelector(
  regionsSelector,
  cellTypeSelector,
  subTypeSelector,
  genesSelector,
  backgroundColorSelector,
  depthWriteSelector,
  radiusScaleSelector,
  geneExpressionLevelScaleSelector,
  (selectedRegions, selectedCellTypes, selectedSubTypes, selectedGenes,backgroundColor,depthWrite,radiusScale,geneExpressionLevelScale) => ({
    regions: selectedRegions,
    cellTypes: selectedCellTypes,
    subTypes: selectedSubTypes,
    genes: selectedGenes,
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    depthWrite: depthWrite,
    radiusScale: radiusScale,
    geneExpressionLevelScale: geneExpressionLevelScale,
  }),
);


export default function TestComponent() {
  console.log("Test Componet")

  const selectedOptions = useSelector(selectedOptionsSelector,shallowEqual);

  useEffect (()=> {
    console.log('Selected Options:', selectedOptions.regions,selectedOptions.subTypes,selectedOptions.cellTypes,selectedOptions.genes)

  },[selectedOptions.regions,selectedOptions.subTypes,selectedOptions.cellTypes,selectedOptions.genes])


  useEffect (()=>{
    console.log('Settings: ', )
  },[selectedOptions.backgroundColor,selectedOptions.radiusScale,selectedOptions.depthWrite])

  return <div><h1>testComponent</h1></div>

}
```

```
Why does the useEffect hook execute when there's a change in Redux state, even if that specific state is not included in the hook's dependency array?
```

I have this react component to simulate behavior my application, The Problem I am having is that both of the useEffect run when only backgroundColor, radiusScale and depthWrite. On the other hand when only one of [selectedOptions.regions,selectedOptions.subTypes,selectedOptions.cellTypes,selectedOptions.genes] changes then only the first useEffect is run. Can someone please explain this behaviour and possible provide a solution?

The problem is after it is mounted once.

Comment: Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Yes I just created one,
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-swanson-z8gh9w?file=/src/components/TestComponet.js

You can try to check or uncheck depthWrite checkbox and you will see that both useEffect are run even though only one of the useEffect have depthWrite as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both effects run mostly because you are selecting too much state. You've created 8 state selectors, but then merged them app back into 1 selected object with `useSelector`.

```js
const selectedOptionsSelector = createSelector(
  [
    regionsSelector,
    cellTypeSelector,
    subTypeSelector,
    genesSelector,
    backgroundColorSelector,
    depthWriteSelector,
    radiusScaleSelector,
    geneExpressionLevelScaleSelector
  ],
  (
    selectedRegions,
    selectedCellTypes,
    selectedSubTypes,
    selectedGenes,
    backgroundColor,
    depthWrite,
    radiusScale,
    geneExpressionLevelScale
  ) => ({
    regions: selectedRegions,
    cellTypes: selectedCellTypes,
    subTypes: selectedSubTypes,
    genes: selectedGenes,
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    depthWrite: depthWrite,
    radiusScale: radiusScale,
    geneExpressionLevelScale: geneExpressionLevelScale
  })
);
```

```js
const selectedOptions = useSelector(selectedOptionsSelector, shallowEqual);
```

Even though you are using the `shallowEqual` utility function, this doesn't do a deep enough equality check. It only checks the root-level properties.

See [shallowEqual](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/2210db90987beaa9ab1a374d60b55a7cfa23072a/src/utils/shallowEqual.ts#L9-L36)

> ```
> function is(x: unknown, y: unknown) {
>   if (x === y) {
>     return x !== 0 || y !== 0 || 1 / x === 1 / y
>   } else {
>     return x !== x && y !== y
>   }
> }
>
> export default function shallowEqual(objA: any, objB: any) {
>   if (is(objA, objB)) return true
>
>   if (
>     typeof objA !== 'object' ||
>     objA === null ||
>     typeof objB !== 'object' ||
>     objB === null
>   ) {
>     return false
>   }
>
>   const keysA = Object.keys(objA)
>   const keysB = Object.keys(objB)
>
>   if (keysA.length !== keysB.length) return false
>
>   for (let i = 0; i < keysA.length; i++) {
>     if (
>       !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(objB, keysA[i]) ||
>       !is(objA[keysA[i]], objB[keysA[i]])
>     ) {
>       return false
>     }
>   }
>
>   return true
> }
> ```

If you select each state individually then the "other" effect isn't triggered when unrelated state is updated.

Example:

```js
function TestComponent() {
  console.log("Test Component");

  const selectedOptions = useSelector(selectedOptionsSelector, shallowEqual);

  const regions = useSelector(regionsSelector, shallowEqual);
  const subTypes = useSelector(subTypeSelector, shallowEqual);
  const cellTypes = useSelector(subTypeSelector, shallowEqual);
  const genes = useSelector(genesSelector, shallowEqual);
  const backgroundColor = useSelector(backgroundColorSelector);
  const radiusScale = useSelector(radiusScaleSelector);
  const depthWrite = useSelector(depthWriteSelector);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "Selected Options 1:",
      selectedOptions.regions,
      selectedOptions.subTypes,
      selectedOptions.cellTypes,
      selectedOptions.genes
    );
  }, [
    selectedOptions.regions,
    selectedOptions.subTypes,
    selectedOptions.cellTypes,
    selectedOptions.genes
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Selected Options 2:", regions, subTypes, cellTypes, genes);
  }, [regions, subTypes, cellTypes, genes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "Settings 1: ",
      selectedOptions.backgroundColor,
      selectedOptions.radiusScale,
      selectedOptions.depthWrite
    );
  }, [
    selectedOptions.backgroundColor,
    selectedOptions.radiusScale,
    selectedOptions.depthWrite
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Settings 2: ", backgroundColor, radiusScale, depthWrite);
  }, [backgroundColor, radiusScale, depthWrite]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>testComponent</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the "Depth Write` checkbox is toggled, now the "Selected Options 1" (because issue with selector) and both "Settings 1" and "Settings 2" effects are triggered when any "settings 2" state is updated. The "Selected Options 2" effect isn't triggered as expected.

[image: Edit why-does-the-useeffect-hook-execute-when-theres-a-change-in-redux-state-even-i]

Comment: Yes I understand upon individual state selection, the issue is solved Thanks alot!